Browser back button didn't gave me time to show the modal
This is my js code first i have tried if someone made changes in fields then this modal shows if i tried to go other pages without saving. That's work fine for me. But on browser back button a problem shows it didn't show the modal and goes back. So i have use this onbeforeunload so it can work now it's work but didn't gave me time to click on modal buttons that i made for them to stay on the page leave to that new page on the click of stay button it should stay on that page and on click of delete button it should go to that clicked page but modal didn't show for a second when i click on browser back button it goes back immediately


var modal = $(".leave_modal");
var modalContent = modal.find(".modal-content");
var deleteBtn = modal.find(".close");
var stayBtn = modal.find(".btn-stay");
var saveBtn = $("#saveBtn");
var clickedLinkURL; // Set initial styles for modal content 
modalContent.css({
  transition: "transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease",
  transform: "scale(0.8)",
  opacity: 0
});

function openModal() {
  modal.css("display", "block");
  setTimeout(function() {
    modalContent.css({
      transform: "scale(1)",
      opacity: 1
    });
  }, 50);
}

function closeModal() {
  modalContent.css({
    transform: "scale(0.8)",
    opacity: 0
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    modal.css("display", "none");
  }, 300);
}
deleteBtn.on("click", function() {
  closeModal();
  $("body").off("click", "a", preventLinkClick);
  if (clickedLinkURL) {
    window.location.href = clickedLinkURL;
    // Redirect to the URL of the clicked link 
  }
});
stayBtn.on("click", closeModal);
$(window).on("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target === modal[0]) {
    closeModal();
  }
});

function preventLinkClick(event) {
  var target = $(event.target);
  if (target.is("a") && target.attr("href") && target.attr("href") !== "#") {
    if ($("#changesMade").val() === "true") {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default only if changes have been made 
      clickedLinkURL = target.attr("href"); // Store the URL of the clicked link  
      openModal();
    } else {}
  }
}
$("body").on("click", "a", preventLinkClick); // Function to set changesMade to true when changes are detected  
$("input, select, textarea").on("input change", function() {
  $("#changesMade").val("true");
});
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
  if (changesMade) {
    openModal();
    return null;
  }
};

function showConfirmationModal(url) {}




beforeunload is not really meant for you to be showing any custom stuff. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event: "The main use case for this event is to trigger a browser-generated confirmation dialog that asks users to confirm if they really want to leave the page when they try to close or reload it, or navigate somewhere else. This is intended to help prevent loss of unsaved data." - emphasis in bold by me.

So how can i made the browser back button working back. Because i need that back button working back it didn't show me the message. On another place my modal is working fine
